# How to pass params to uiComponent without caching?

Tags: magento2, php, uicomponent

I have some issue with initialization uiComponent and passing parameters to component.

So I have code, example below:

```
 <?php

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\View\AddTo\Wishlist $block */
$productStatus = $block->getData('productStatus');
?>
<?php if ($block->isWishListAllowed()) : ?>
    <div data-bind="scope: 'wishListComponent'">
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    </div>

    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "*": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                    "components": {
                        "wishListComponent": {
                            "component": "addToWishlistComponent",
                            "params": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getWishlistParams() ?>,
                            "isAdded": "<?= /* @noEscape */ $productStatus->isAddedToWishlist($block->getProduct()) ?>"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "body": {
            "addToWishlist": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getWishlistOptionsJson() ?>
        }
    }
</script>
```

My problem - i can`t pass correct data on this line:

```
"isAdded": "<?= /* @noEscape */ $productStatus->isAddedToWishlist($block->getProduct()) ?>"
```

Because Magento cache it and after each reloading page i get the same data, but after reloading page data should be changed, and i have to get changed data (  It work correctly only after cache clearing, but it is not what i want.

So. How i can solve this (without turn off cache) ? Maybe my solution is wrong and there is better way to pass data like this ? 
Thanks )

Comment: It's worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get Data from customer Data local storage and you pass

like below:

```
            this.wishlist = customerData.get('wishlist');
         var wishListItems = this.wishlist().items;
        $.each( wishListItems, function( index, item ) {
            if(item.product_id === id) {
               //do your code here or pass data as per your requirement
            }
        });
```

you can get all the added wishlist data here

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i confused, when i try to get wishlist items  i get correct information about counter but items array is  incorrect  https://ibb.co/gR3158y. Do you was facing with similar problem ?

Comment: yes therefor you have to check \Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist  getItems method where SIDEBAR_ITEMS_NUMBER variable used overide this method and remove this limit @maybe_vp

Comment: I think it good solution for me. But i faced with some strange thing,  after added to wishlist item appears in customerData after second page refresh. 
What do i mean: I added product to wishlist -> refresh page(there no item  in customerData) -> refresh  again (item there is in customerData).
Do you have any idea ? It's my mistake ?

Comment: I have used thing in many projects and data update not work in page refresh ....so it's not issue of wish list... may be other js interrupt ... please check your console may be you can found something

Comment: Figured out and it was my mistake. Thank you very much it very useful thing )